# Как передать параметры в php файл из bash

Tags: php, sh

Есть sh файл в нем строка

```
php cdr.php arg1 arg2
```

При запуске sh файла в php не передаются параметры arg1 и arg2.
Подскажите как правильно написать команду.

Comment: Каким образом Вы запускаете sh файл? Приведите всю строку запуска и "начинку" самого файла.

Comment: @Dejsving, запуская ./cdr.sh, #!/bin/sh

php /var/BGBilling/scripts/bgbilling.php cdr

Comment: ключевой вопрос тут, как вы их получаете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваш скрипт запуска выглядит, как-то так:

```
#!/bin/sh
php index.php -pvalue qwe
```

то перечень передаваемых параметров в вызываемом скрипте вы можете получить, используя [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php). В данном случае это будут

```
0 => index.php
1 => -pvalue
2 => qwe
```

Для получения значений параметров можете использовать [`getopt()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.getopt.php). Например, `getopt("p")` вернет значение `value`. Значения можно писать слитно, через пробел и знак равенства. Обязательные и не обязательны параметры обозначаются через `:` или `::` и так далее согласно документации.

Answer (score -1):

Ответ в документации
http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.argv.php

Первый пример - ответ на Ваш вопрос